# Convert java.sql.ResultSet to stream in java 8

Tags: java, mysql, java-8

I had written a service for querying data from SQL.

```
public class DummyDeviceTokenService {
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public DummyDeviceTokenService() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student?"
                        + "user=root&password=root");

        statement = connect.createStatement();
    }

    public ResultSet selectAll(int offset,int range)throws Exception{
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("select * from employee where id > " + offset + " AND id < "+range);
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

I want to return a stream from `public ResultSet selectAll(int offset,int range)`.

I went through [java.util.stream with ResultSet - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209248/java-util-stream-with-resultset) but these were little complex methods.

Please suggest some good way to do this.

Comment: Holger already suggested the good way to do this. Look no further unless you prefer simplicity over correctness.

Comment: The only alternative is to wait for a 3rd party library or future Java version providing you exactly that functionality in an easy-to-use method.

Comment: I answered the question below. take a look if it's what you're looking for.