# Java Streams to iterate over a ResultSet object

Tags: java-8, java-stream, resultset

I have the following code snippet

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); 
List<String> userIdList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
while(rs.next()){
    userIdList.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Can I make use of Java streams/Lambda expressions to perform this iteration instead of a while loop to populate the List?

Comment: If you want to use one of `Stream`’s factory methods, you’re out of luck as the “iterate until `next()` returns `false`” logic cannot be expressed with them in Java 8. There will be support in Java 9, however, the checked `SQLException` prevents you from writing concise lambda expressions. You’ll most likely end up with a custom `Spliterator`, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32232173/2711488), which covers a bit more than just iterating over the `ResultSet`. That’s useful as a factory when you will use it often, but for converting a single loop, it would be overkill.

Answer (score 12):

You may create a wrapper for the `ResultSet` making it an `Iterable`. From there you can iterate as well as create a stream. Of course you have to define a mapper function to get the iterated values from the result set.

The `ResultSetIterable` may look like this

```
public class ResultSetIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  private final ResultSet rs;
  private final Function<ResultSet, T> onNext;

  public ResultSetIterable(ResultSet rs, CheckedFunction<ResultSet, T> onNext){
    this.rs = rs;
    //onNext is the mapper function to get the values from the resultSet
    this.onNext = onNext;
  }

  private boolean resultSetHasNext(){
     try {
       hasNext = rs.next();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
       //you should add proper exception handling here
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
  }


  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {

    try {
        return new Iterator<T>() {

            //the iterator state is initialized by calling next() to 
            //know whether there are elements to iterate
            boolean hasNext = resultSetHasNext();


            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return hasNext;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {

                T result = onNext.apply(rs);
                //after each get, we need to update the hasNext info
                hasNext = resultSetHasNext();
                return result;
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //you should add proper exception handling here
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  //adding stream support based on an iteratable is easy
  public Stream<T> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(this.spliterator(), false);
  }
}
```

Now that we have our wrapper, you could stream over the results:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); 
List<String> userIdList = new ResultSetIterable(rs, rs -> rs.getString(1)).stream()
                                                                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

}

### EDIT

As Lukas pointed out, the `rs.getString(1)` may throw a checked `SQLException`, therefor we need to use a `CheckedFunction` instead of a java `Function` that would be capable of wrapping any checked Exception in an unchecked one. 
A very simple implementation could be

```
public interface CheckedFunction<T,R> extends Function<T,R> {

  @Override
  default R apply(T t) {

    try {
        return applyAndThrow(t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  R applyAndThrow(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

Alternatively you could use a library with such a function, i.e. [jooλ](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.9/org/jooq/lambda/fi/util/function/CheckedFunction.html) or [vavr](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/CheckedFunction1.html)

Comment: Or you can use `org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetIterator.iterable(rowSet)`

Comment: This doesn't work. `Function` doesn't allow for throwing `SQLException`, so your lambda `rs -> rs.getString(1)` doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Could be solved by using a "CheckedFunction" instead, that would allow for code that throws checked Exception

Comment: ... Speaking of which, your `boolean hasNext = rs.next();` also throws an uncaught checked exception in the iterator constructor. The wrapping try catch is not applicable here.

Comment: fixing that would make "copy and pasting from stackoverflow" way too easy :)

Answer (score 3):

If using a third party library is an option, you could use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org), which supports wrapping JDBC `ResultSet` in jOOQ [`Cursor`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html) types, and then stream them. For example, using [`DSLContext.fetchStream()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchStream-java.sql.ResultSet-)

Essentially, you could write:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    DSL.using(con)                       // DSLContext
       .fetchStream(rs)                  // Stream<Record>
       .map(r -> r.get(0, String.class)) // Stream<String>
       .collect(toList());
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Try library: [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc)

```
List<String> userIdList = StreamEx.<String> rows(resultSet, 1).toList(); // Don't forget to close ResultSet
```

Or: If you want to close the `ResultSet` after `toList`.

```
StreamEx.<String> rows(resultSet, 1).onClose(() -> JdbcUtil.closeQuitely(resultSet)).toList();
```

Or: If you use the utility classes provided in `abacus-jdbc`:

```
String sql = "select user_id from user";
// No need to worry about closing Connection/Statement/ResultSet manually. It will be took care by the framework.
JdbcUtil.prepareQuery(dataSource, sql).stream(String.class).toList();
// Or:
JdbcUtil.prepareQuery(dataSource, sql).toList(String.class);
```

Disclaimer：I'm the developer of [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc).