# Reading data from database and store in List of Model class type in java8

Tags: java, mysql, java-8

I want to display content of table based on entries returned by my select query and store in ArrayList of Model class type. I have achieved my goal using java7 .But I want to do the same using java 8 streams concept. I am totally new to java 8.

my java7 code

```
public static ArrayList<Customer> getAllCustomer() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
Connection conn=DBConnection.getDBConnection().getConnection();
Statement stm;
stm = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "Select * From Customer";
ResultSet rst;
rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
while (rst.next()) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(rst.getString("id"), rst.getString("name"), rst.getString("address"), rst.getDouble("salary"));
    customerList.add(customer);
}
return customerList;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to convert to a `Stream`, and why? There doesn't seem to be much application for it here.

Comment: You may want to review the following:  https://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql

Comment: There is no builtin solution to create a `Stream` from a `ResultSet` and implementing it is not trivial. See [java.util.stream with ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32209248/2711488).

Comment: Thanx @PM77-1. It was helpful.