# How to get all remaining rows from ResultSet java sql package

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I used to use com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet. I could take all remaining rows and put it into an Array of my model class and then add it to List of Arrays.

Below is my previous code with ResultSet from datastax package.

```
List<ReportDescription[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
ReportDescription[] csvReportDescriptions;
csvReportDescriptions = resultSet.all().stream()
                    .map(row -> new ReportDescription(row.getObject("value"))).toArray(ReportDescription[]::new);
result.add(csvReportDescriptions);
```

Nowadays I change database so now I need to swithch ResultSet to java.sql.ResultSet package. Is it any possibility to get all rows, create new instance of my models and put it into List of Arrays as I did it before?

**I make it by my own like that**

```
try {
ResultSet rS = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query.toString());
    while(rS.next()){
        descriptions.add(new ReportDescription(rS.getObject("VALUE")));
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
                dataSource.logError("Can't execute statement :" + query.toString());
    }               

    csvReportDescriptions = descriptions.toArray(new ReportDescription[descriptions.size()]);
    result.add(csvReportDescriptions);
```

Comment: This seems to have something similar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209248/java-util-stream-with-resultset

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help me - I can not get rows

Comment: You could convert it to an Iterator (using https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/ResultSetIterator.html#ResultSetIterator-java.sql.ResultSet-)and then stream the iterator. Or you could simply do what piotr has done

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to retrieve data from `ResultSet` in a Java8 way using `Streams`, So there are multiple ways to do it.

How we write SQL in **Java 7** using **[JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)**

```
List<Schema> result = new ArrayList<>();
try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
    String sql = "select schema_name, is_default " +
                 "from information_schema.schemata " +
                 "order by schema_name";

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(
                new Schema(rs.getString("SCHEMA_NAME"),
                           rs.getBoolean("IS_DEFAULT"))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

How we write SQL in **Java 8** using **[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL)**

```
try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
    String sql = "select schema_name, is_default " +
                 "from information_schema.schemata " +
                 "order by schema_name";

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql) {

        // We can wrap a Statement or a ResultSet in a
        // Java 8 ResultSet Stream
        SQL.stream(stmt, Unchecked.function(rs ->
            new Schema(
                rs.getString("SCHEMA_NAME"),
                rs.getBoolean("IS_DEFAULT")
            )
        ))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

How we write SQL in **Java 8** using **[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)**

```
try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
    String sql = "select schema_name, is_default " +
                 "from information_schema.schemata " +
                 "order by schema_name";

    DSL.using(c)
       .fetch(sql)

       // We can use lambda expressions to map jOOQ Records
       .map(rs -> new Schema(
           rs.getValue("SCHEMA_NAME", String.class),
           rs.getValue("IS_DEFAULT", boolean.class)
       ))

       // ... and then profit from the new Collection methods
       .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

How we write SQL in **Java 8** using **[Spring JDBC](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/)**

```
try (Connection c = getConnection()) {
    String sql = "select schema_name, is_default " +
                 "from information_schema.schemata " +
                 "order by schema_name";

    new JdbcTemplate(
            new SingleConnectionDataSource(c, true))

        // We can use lambda expressions as RowMappers
        .query(sql, (rs, rowNum) ->
            new Schema(
                rs.getString("SCHEMA_NAME"),
                rs.getBoolean("IS_DEFAULT")
            ))

        // ... and then profit from the new Collection methods
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Source: [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot. This is because `ResultSet` was originally created with support for databases that have cursor support - all of your results might not even be in the database server's memory, nor can it be viable to actually download all of them.

What you can do is simply traverse the result set adding all the results to a list with the help of some boilerplate code:

```
List<ReportDescription> descs = new ArrayList<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    descs.add(new ReportDescription(resultSet.getObject("value")));
}
```

EDIT: To expand on the answer - a `ResultSet` actually always holds a cursor to a row (or a special quasi-row: *before first* or *after last*). Therefore, any getters you call on a `ResultSet` actually fetch the respective data from the row the cursor points to (or throw an exception if it's not on any row).

Comment: It is not a problem to make a List of ReportDescription however I need an array of ReportDesciption.

Comment: You can transform a list to an array using the `toArray()` method.

Comment: Could you please help me? `List<ReportDescription> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();` `descriptions.add(new ReportDescription(rS.getObject("VALUE")));``result.add(descriptions.stream().toArray(ReportDescription[]::new));` I tried like that but it is still bad. I would like to have all ReportDescribtions in 1st index of list