# How to return java8 Stream from jdbc result set

Tags: java-8, java-stream, spring-jdbc, spring-4

To make best use of the java8 stream and Spring4, I use the Stream API as follows on a JDBC resultSet that comes from Springs jsdbRestTemplate (code shortened and simplified):

```java
public <T> T consumeResultStream(
    String query, 
    Function<Stream<String>, T> extractorFunction
) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
        query, 
        resultSet -> {
            Spliterator<String> spliterator = 
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                    new Iterator<String>() {
                      @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                        return !resultSet.isAfterLast();
                      }
                      @Override public String next() {
                        String result = resultSet.getString(0);
                        resultSet.next();
                        return result;
                      }
                    }, 
                    Spliterator.IMMUTABLE);
           resultStream = StreamSupport.stream(
               spliterator, /*parallel*/ false);
       }
       return extractorFunction.apply(resultStream);
    });
}
```

This seems to work fine. Clients can use the stream Api like this without worrying about jdbc classes

```java
List<T> myResult = consumeResultStream("SELECT ...", stream -> 
    stream.filter((String s) -> ...)
        .map(String s -> toT(s))
        .collect(toList()));
```

However, when I refactor (trying to provide the stream to client methods instead), like this:

```java
    final Stream<String> stream = 
        jdbcTemplate.query(query, resultSet -> {
          // ... same as above
          return resultStream;
        });
    return extractorFunction.apply(stream);
```

I get

```
org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: 
  The object is already closed [90007-199]
```

So it seems the data can only be read within the `jdbcTemplate.query()` method. Is there a clean way I can circumvent this and return a **lazy** stream of the elements coming from the DB? Assume materializing the result and streaming that is not an option because of the size of the results (though pagination might be a better pattern).

Comment: `jdbcTemplate.query(...)` encapsulates an operation which processes the result set and closes it. It can't return a lazy stream. On the other hand, when you provide an SQL statement and process the `ResultSet` manually, why not work with `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` directly? Besides that, it's straight-forward to implement a `Spliterator` rather than an `Iterator`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32209248/2711488

Comment: I guess my question here can be closed as duplicate of the linked one. Now I worry if it's smart leave closing the streams to others.

Comment: That's how, e.g `Files.lines()` and `Files.list()`, work.

Answer (score 0):

`JdbcTemplate` doesn't handle transaction beyond its invocation contrary to Spring `JPA` feature.
To not allow that the DB connection be closed, open a transaction from the client side that manipulates the returned lazy result.
Annotating it with `@Transactional` is generally enough :

```
@Transactional
public void findLazyData(){
   Stream<String> result = dataAccessService.find(...);
   // where find() contains the JdbcTemplate invocation
}
```

Note the package origin : `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

Comment: I tried, but still same result. I verified Transactions and tests are set up correctly running `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()` in the method, which return a valid object (if I remove annotations I get NoTransactionException).